# HTML request using a PLC

Tags: string, https, http-post, httprequest, plc

I am trying to make a get/post request to a multi-purpose modem for web interface and gsm interface using a PLC(Programmable Logic Controller). 
I have been trying to send string data to the modem through the TCP library currently with Schneider Somachine. Every time I make a request, I receive an Error 400 bad request. I am hoping that my program is correct as I can receive an error statement via the modem, but am not sure about the request I need to make in order to receive a positive OK response from the controller.

I have tried making the following requests and all returned with an Error 400 bad request.

1. GET https://192.168.2.1
2. GET https://192.168.2.1/api/login?username=admin&password=admin
3. I have also tried the above without the GET statement and with POST statements as well.

The above requests were done with carriage return and new line characters in the end. 
I would really appreciate if someone could help out with the request type that has to be made in order to get that response.

Comment: Not enough information. You need to look at the raw request as it comes in at 192.168.2.1 to see what's wrong with it. Run wireshark.

Comment: What more information do you need?
As i mentioned, the PLC is communicating with the rCell modem, there is no way I can view it through a wireshark, there is a lot of disturbances through its own network.

Comment: "there is a lot of disturbances through its own network" Do you know if you can reliably create/terminate a TCP connection, regardless of the protocol?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, the connection is established effectively. The PLC sends the requests mentioned above to the modem and in return i get an Error 400 for bad request. So I am certain that there is a connection but I am not sure what the request should look like in order to make it through the PLC.

Comment: from w3.org: _10.4.1 400 Bad Request - The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications._  I would wire-shark it and compare it against the spec to see how/what is malformed.  Since you are going through a library, it could be your code, it could be the library code.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, accessing PLC through ajax is not a routine operation. If you can, you can try LECPServer, an open source middleware. It can expose the PLC node address for reading and writing through HTTP POST.

https://github.com/xeden3/LECPServer

Answer (score 0):

Your requests are malformed (that's why you get the 400 response).

It should look like:

```
GET /path/to/resource/index.html HTTP/1.0
```

The server (192.168.2.1) and the transport (http vs https) have already been taken care of by the connection. All you're trying to do is tell the device what you want to do. In this case you want to access the login page with your credentials. You also need to specify which version of the protocol to use.

```
Get /api/login?username=admin&password=admin HTTP/1.0
```